# Ex-dividend dates for Nikkei and Dow Jones on CFD and Spread Bet Markets?

Tags: dividends, spreads, cfd, ex-dividend-date

I've found a few ex-dividend date sites for the Dow Jones (can't find any decent ones for the Japanese Nikkei Index). However the ex-dividend dates don't seem to match when I get dividend payouts on my CFD/Spread bet account, the US seems to have ex-dividend dates almost every other day, but I get paid them once a week, is there a list of dates somewhere for when they payout for CFD traders? For any index?

Answer (score 2):

You should check this with your Broker or CFD Provider, because if you are trading CFDs your Broker/CFD Provider would be paying you the dividends, as you are trading CFDs which are a derivative of the underlying and are provided by your Broker/CFD Provider.

Comment: I asked my provider and they said they do not keep a list :-s they are city index.